# to use umlaut in urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

These days web addresses can also include non-ASCII characters. So every modern browser and webserver is ready to handle UTF-8 URI. There is any "con" to use it today? I mean, a lot of people will say "it will break old browsers, bla bla bla", but since, we assume javascript support, we don't support more IE6, is it ok if i assume that all modern browsers will be able to handle urls with öäü in the url? Because my application (db, framework, webserver) is full utf-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They should handle it.

BUT: how does the user enter it?

If you SHOW them in coded form, they are ugly.

If you show them in "native" form - how would YOU enter a french acccent or a chinese symbol;) Just out of curiosity. I would not know how to ;)

Comment: Segmentation. I dont have fear to make a chinese job website focusing to target nothing but chinese speaking workers. Polarization is good, not always one size fits all ;-)

Comment: You can google for the symbol and use copy & paste to insert it into the address bar. Or you can learn all the unicode sequences and type them directly on your keyboard. I don't see a problem there ;)

Comment: Christoph, /städte/Köln as resource, für mich, ist besser als /staedte/Koeln. Specially because we created this "workaround" when DB, WebServer and Browsers didn't support UTF-8. Today its different, we should prefer it than other encodes..

Comment: Uh, @TomTom, how do you enter Latin characters on a non-Latin keyboard? Your answer is very English-centric. Russians don't have Latin characters on their keyboards, for example, and have to access them the same way you access French accents. Please don't assume that the internet is used by speakers of English only.